# How to extract SOAP response using pysimplesoap?

Tags: pysimplesoap

I am new on using pysimplesoap. I am succeed using pysimplesoap to generate a soap request to a SOAP server, and the soap server is responded correctly, however, I do not know how to extract the information returned.

This is my code on pysimplesoap for the request

```
> from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
> client = SoapClient(location="http://192.168.206.111:8998/axis2/services/SecurityService", action="", namespace="http://www.labtest.com/Security", ns="ns3")
> response = client.call("login", ("ns3:loginName", "administrator"), ("ns3:password", "admin"))
```

The SOAP response is in below format.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <n:loginResponse
                xmlns:n="http://www.labtest.com/Security"
                xmlns:n0="http://www.labtest.com/Types">
                <n:errorCode>
                    <n0:hasError>
                        false
                        </n0:hasError>
                    <n0:status>
                        STATUS_SUCCESS
                        </n0:status>
                    </n:errorCode>
                <n:authorizationToken>
                    <n0:token>
                        6430303938366138316265646532313138623866353235343030346130653330
                        </n0:token>
                    <n0:securityPrivileges>
                        <n0:values>
                            <n0:securityAttribute>
                                SUPER_USER_ACCESS
                                </n0:securityAttribute>
                            <n0:accessRights>
                                <n0:values>
                                    FULL_CONTROL
                                    </n0:values>
                                </n0:accessRights>
                            </n0:values>
                        </n0:securityPrivileges>
                    </n:authorizationToken>
                </n:loginResponse>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to use the print response or print (response), but nothing show up.

Answer (score 2):

The `response` object is a **pysimplesoap.client.SimpleXMLElement**.

Behind the hood, a `print(response)` will call its `__str__()` method, the choice have been made, for pysimplesoap that `` `__str__() `` returns the text content of the node (if any), if your node contains no text content, like :

```
<MySoapResponse>
    <child tag attr="value />
</MySoapResponse>
```

… then, `__str__()` will return nothing, and so do printing.

Alternatively, you may want to

- **navigate the XML tree** of your answer by using SimpleXMLElement methods :

  - `children()` to grab childrens list
  - `tag['attr']` (dict notation) to access attributes of an XML tag
  - `tag.get_name()` to get a tag name ;
- **inspect the full answer** as a string (including Soap headers) as string calling `repr(response)`, but it's more for debugging purposes.

See also [the basic client documentation](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SoapClient) online.